# Chain .ready and .resize into function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, object, triggers

Inside this object, I have a property `Response.action` that is meant to be a shorthand for triggering code on jQuery's `.ready` and `.resize` simultaneously. The comment in the code block below demonstrates its usage. `Response.action` works on `.ready` but not on `.resize`. Can anyone see why and/or suggest how to make it work for both?

```
window.Response = (function($, window, undefined) {

    var Response = {},  // object
        $window = $(window),
        $document = $(document); // cache selectors 

    /*
    Response.action()
    This triggers code on .ready *and* .resize 
    usage:
                Response.action( myactions );
                function myactions() { 
                    // do stuff
                }       
    */  
    action = function( code ) { 

        var code = ( code !== undefined ) ? wrap() : false; // apply wrap() if we have code

        function wrap() {
            $document.ready(function() {
                $window.resize(function() {
                    code // input
                }).resize(); // trigger resize handlers
            }); // close .ready function
        }

        return code; // wrapped code fires on .ready and .resize
    },
    Response.action = action;

    return Response; // return object

})(jQuery, window); // expose to global object
```

This is for [responsejs.com](http://responsejs.com/) - the full lib (in progress) is there.

I'm using one of the other properties to test it. The `.band` property is solid on its own:

```
Response.action( myactions() );
function myactions() { 
        if ( Response.band(600) ) { $('header').html('600px or wider'); }
        else { $('header').html('below 600px');  }
}
```

**Update**: this works:

Response.action = function ( func ) {
    if ( typeof func !== 'function' ) { return false; }

```
$(function () {
    func();
    $window.resize( func );
}).resize();

return func;
```

};

with this usage syntax:

```
Response.action( myactions );
function myactions() { 
        // do stuff
}
```

*Note that in the call it needs to be `myactions` as opposed to `myactions()`

Comment: You're missing `var` for the "action" variable ... Also instead of just "code", it should probably be "code()".

Comment: Also it's making me dizzy trying to figure out what value "code" will have inside the "resize" handler.

Comment: @Pointy `action` doesn't need `var`. It is equiv. to putting `Response.action = {}` I learned that from Modernizr. It definitely works for other properties in the lib.

Comment: @Pointy The idea is to make it easier to pass a block of code into both. The value of `code` would be the function the you pass from outside. (see the `usage:` comment)

Comment: @Pointy `function( code() )` throws an `unexpected (` error.

Comment: @ryanve When you don't declare a variable (like `action` in your case), it becomes a global property. You don't want that. Therefore, put a `var ` in front of it.

Comment: @Pointy Re: "dizzy" The `var code =` line uses the ternary operator.

Comment: @ryanve no, you definitely need `var` on "action".  Currently, it's a **global variable**.  It doesn't matter that you later set a property on your "Response" object to the same value.

Comment: @Pointy @Šime Vidas Adding `var` throws `unexpected token` and `Response is not defined` errors. I understand the badness of global vars. How do I make it work like that then?

Comment: @ryanve That's because you use the comma operator (which is another thing that I recommend against). My suggestion: `var action = function () { ... }; // <-- semicolon here instead of comma` and then `Response.action = action;`

Comment: @Šime Vidas Nice - the semicolon worked for that. I thought commas were faster (and recommended for most var declarations.) But it still only works on `.ready` and not `.resize`

Comment: @ryanve `code` is a string? How do you execute it?

Comment: @Šime Vidas I updated the question with how I'm testing it. It's a function. Here is a temp link to the test: http://responsejs.com/test0.php You can see the "600px" text appears on `.ready` but it fails to change on `.resize`.

Comment: @ryanve Since `myactions` doesn't return anything, this `Response.action( myactions() );` is equivalent to this `myactions(); Response.action( undefined );`. You probably want this `Response.action( myactions );`, right?

Comment: @Šime Vidas Yes, good call. That is key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
window.Response = (function ( $, window, undefined ) {

    var Response = {};

    Response.action = function ( func ) {
        if ( typeof func !== 'function' ) { return false; }

        $(function () {
            func();
            $( window ).resize( func );
        });

        return func;
    };

    return Response;

})( jQuery , window );
```

Comment: Trying it now / thanks. That `if` is definitely a better way to handle the `!code` part.

Comment: I just updated the question with the working example. I'm definitely giving you a shout out when I publish the lib—thank you :)

Comment: You think it's possible get it to work on an array too? » http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375158/using-each-to-execute-array-of-functions-on-resize