# using .each to execute array of functions on .resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, each

In the an object called `Response` this works to trigger a function on `.ready` and `.resize` simultaneously...

```
Response.action = function ( func ) {
    if ( typeof func !== 'function' ) { return false; } // If func is not a function, return false.
        $(function () { func(); $(window).resize( func ); }); // 
    return func;
}; // Response.action
```

...using this to call it:

```
Response.action( myfunc );
function myfunc() { 
    //do stuff
}
```

(We worked that out in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372852/chain-ready-and-resize-into-function).)

I'd like to make another version that can do the same thing for an **array** of functions, with usage like this:

```
Response.actionSet( [myfunc1, myfunc2] );
function myfunc1() { 
    //do stuff
}
function myfunc2() { 
    //do stuff
}
```

I tried it as below and every other incantation I could imagine, but I haven't got it to work. No error messages either. Can anyone recommend how to get this working:

```
Response.actionSet = function ( arr ) {
        if ( arr.isArray !== true ) { return false; } // If arr is not an array, return false.
        $.each(arr, Response.action(this)); // iterate over arr array
        return arr;
}; // Response.actionSet
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a small error; it should be `$.each(arr, function() { Response.action(this); });`

```
Response.actionSet = function(arr) {
    if(!$.isArray(arr)) return false;
    $.each(arr, function() { Response.action(this); });
    return arr;
};
```

Comment: Tried it (thanks) but that doesn't work either. Worth noting is that if I change the callback to `Response.actionSet( [myfunc1(), myfunc2()] );` then it works on `.ready` but not on `.resize`. Without the parenthesis, `Response.actionSet` gives nothing. `Response.action` only worked for the `.resize` without the parenthesis so I figure this needs to be the same.

Comment: @ryanve Well, if you add `()`, you're invoking those functions on the spot (before even entering `actionSet`), so it obviously works "onready", duh `:)`

Comment: Alxandr, @Šime Vidas You're both rockstars!!